# Adobe AIR & Web Service Call. Errors with Error #1085: The element type "br" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</br>"

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, air, adobe

Here is my simple code, which works fine if called from php or any other client then adobe air. Same code also works from calling from SWF, there is fluorineFX code for other part of project as well, but then it doesn't do anything to break this.

I do find one thing that all POST calls were somehow changing to GET, which really amazes me. I would be so glad to get the answer for this. Thanks in Advance everyone. Below is the almost same code from my web service. with AIR code just under it.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public bool Authenticate(string UserName,string Password)
{
    try
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName, Password)){
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and my call from adobe AIR code as below

```
var ws:WebService = new WebService();
ws.wsdl="http://mysite.com/myservice.asmx?WSDL";
ws.useProxy=false;
ws.addEventListener(LoadEvent.LOAD,onWSDLLoad);
ws.loadWSDL();
ws.Authenticate.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,resultHandler);
ws.Authenticate.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,onLoginFaultHandler);
ws.Authenticate("usrname","password");

protected function onLoginFaultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
{
    Alert.show('Login Failed with messsage\r\n[ '+event.fault.faultString+' ]');
    /* Error #1085: The element type "br" must be terminated
      by the matching end-tag "</br>". */
       /* checking the content value of fault event shows
      same out put as http://mysite.com/myservice.asmx */
}

protected function onLoginResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    /* on success code */
}
```

---

This guy tells us following in page http://verveguy.blogspot.com/2008/07/truth-about-flex-httpservice.html

1. All HTTP GET requests are stripped of headers. It's not in the Flex stack so it's probably the underlying Flash player runtime.
2. All HTTP GET requests that have content type other than "application/x-www-form-url-encoded" are turned into POST requests
3. All HTTP POST requests that have no actual posted data are turned into GET requests.   See 1/ and 2/
4. All HTTP PUT and HTTP DELETE requests are turned into POST requests. This appears to be a browser limitation that the Flash player is stuck with.

I do see my request above turns into GET, but then I DO have post values in it. OR if those are somehow are not sent or recorded by Web Service Object  ?

Comment: Interestingly I found thats all calls are turned to GET instead of sending them as POST call. Is there a way to force it to make POST calls for Web Methods ?

Comment: where are you specifying that you would like to call the webmethod `Authenticate` from the webservice? Try this.http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=26

Comment: I think, ws.Authenticate does this call. And its not specific to this method only. All methods fails. with same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself. turns out I was having cookies set to AutoDetect. Which meant that the AIR would call a URL and it would need to redirect to keep the cookie/session value in side the URI itself.

Now I switched that to UseCookies and Everything is back to normal. I could test this from a sample web services and realized it was the server-side that was doing something wrong. And from AIR to Browser that's the only difference of cookies.

Somehow nusoap for PHP is smart to know that there is AutoDetect or New URI of the Web Services available. But AIR couldn't locate that. Anyways Thanks everyone for helping me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple... The Flex XML parser uses strict xml checking, so all tags must be closed. If you can change the web service, then change all `<br>` tags to `<br />`.

Comment: the method is suppose to call the web method which returns just true/false instead it returns me whole web method description page. therefore I feels something wrong in the way the method is called from AIR. is there anything I can do that can solve that problem ?

Comment: Is a regular browser request to the wsdl redirecting to the description page?

Comment: No, the regular requests works all fine. it also works fine from the php soap call.